# How to hide the title bar for main Activity?

Tags: android

I want to remove or hide title bar on top of my app, but only on main Activity, I have 2 more sub activity with navigation bar and blank activity, here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".StartingScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AccommodationScreenWithNav"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_accommodation_screen_with_nav"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartingScreen">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mydomain.test.StartingScreen" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AccommodationDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_accommodation_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".AccommodationScreenWithNav">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mydomain.test.AccommodationScreenWithNav" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

So, I want remove or hide only for main `activity` not for `.AccommodationDetail`

I have tried to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` is work but when I jump to AccommodationDetail activity the app is crash or error.

Please help...

Thanks.

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your theme for your main activity to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, and set your theme for your application to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. If a theme is not explicitly set for an activity, it'll use the theme defined in the application tag.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this -

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 2):

For API Level 11+ devices, you can use:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar
```

Another way to solve this kind of problem is to create your own style in `style.xml` file and set it to a specific activity like Android Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Open your `style.xml` file, create a new style just like below. Choose your own name and set the parent as below

```
<style name="your_own_name" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Open your's project `AndroidManifest.xml` file, set the theme name for the specific activity you dont want the bar to show and you are done

```
<activity  android:theme ="@style/your_own_name" >
</activity>
```

Any questions? Please free to ask.

It should help

Comment: Thanks, and can I add a background image to Navigation bar instead black or light color as a default from the theme??

Answer (score 1):

Before   **setcontentview**  add these two lines in your Activity onCreate() method.

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//hide notification bar
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `platform/android/res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/_MyTheme"/>
    <style name="_MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</resources>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
```